# array size and split of string

Tags: c++, string, split

Ok guy i had to make a program to split elements of a string. And after that print those words.
there are some problems i am facing:
1)  the array prints more than the size of the words in string i want that it should end printing as soon as last word is printed. i tried to prevent that but it always gives runtime error when i try to break at the last word.
2)is there any other efficient way to split and print ???

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <string>   

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    std::getline(cin, line);
    string arr[1000];
    int i = 0;
    int l=line.length();
    stringstream ssin(line);

    while (ssin.good() && i < l)
    {
        ssin >> arr[i];
        ++i;
    }

    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    for(i = 0; i <size; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please fix your code indentation :)

Comment: Try while (ssin >> arr[i++]);

Comment: fixed :) good now ???

Comment: also respond to that extra printing part splitting is done by the code i wrote just that extra print part

Comment: @AlokSrivastava Not perfect, but I'll help you out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
```

That is a compile time value, and it's always going to be the number of elements in your array (1000).  It has no idea how many strings you assigned to in your loop.  You stored the number of successfully read strings (plus 1) in the `i` variable, so you could do this instead:

```
int size = i - 1;
```

But if it were up to me, I would just use a growable structure, like vector (`#include <vector>`)

```
std::vector<std::string> arr;
std::string temp;
while (ssin >> temp)
{
    arr.push_back(temp);
}

for (auto const & str : arr)
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}

/* If you're stuck in the past (can't use C++11)
    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator = arr.begin(); i != arr.end(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << *i << std::endl;
    }
*/
```

For general purpose character based splitting, I would much prefer `boost::split` (I know you can't use it, but for future reference)

```
std::vector<std::string> arr;
boost::split(arr, line, boost::is_any_of(".,;!? "));
```

Comment: If I were the question author, I would mark this as the answer. It's very elegant and exhaustive

Answer (score 1):

Read up on the function strtok.  It is old school but very easy to use.

Comment: Or better, `strtok_r()`. Too bad that this answer will be frowned upon and downvoted for not using nice standard library classes. And jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

1) there are a couple of changes you should make to your program:

```
  #include <sstream>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>   
  using namespace std;
  int main()
  {
    std::string line("hello string world\n");
    string arr[1000];
    int i = 0;
    stringstream ssin(line);
    while (ssin.good() && i < 1000)
    {
      ssin >> arr[i++];
    }
    int size = i-1;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
      cout << i << ": " << arr[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

namely, you don't want to print `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` (i.e. 1000) elements. There is no point in the condition `i < l`

2) `stringstream` is fine if you just want to separate the single strings; if more is needed, use `boost/tokenizer` for splitting strings. It's modern c++, once you try it you'll never come back!

Comment: sorry but those boots wont work in the program submission over various coding websites:(

Answer (score 0):

this is the best method i think no worry now

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>   
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
std::string str;
std::getline(cin, str);
string arr[100];
int l=0,i;

char * cstr = new char [str.length()+1];
std::strcpy (cstr, str.c_str());

 // cstr now contains a c-string copy of str

char * p = std::strtok (cstr,".,;!? ");
while (p!=0)
 {
//std::cout << p << '\n';
arr[l++]=p;
p = strtok(NULL,".,;!? ");
}
for(i = 0; i <l; i++)
{
    cout << arr[i] << endl;
}

delete[] cstr;
return 0;
}
```